# Does something like a tuple-norm exist?

Tags: normed-spaces

I want to visualize high dimensional vectors (n~=10-200) using 2 dimension in a diagram. Over time more and more vectors are added and similar vectors should build clusters, so that it is possible to see changes over time.

Therefore I am looking for an LP-norm ($f$) which maps a vector to a tuple like this:

$$f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} × \mathbb{R}$$

Using variables for the norm like f(x)=(y,z) the trivial case that $∀ x: y=z$ should be ruled out. Another restriction is that the derivative $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{∂ z}{∂ x}$ should be continuous. In other words: changing x a little bit should not result in jumps when plotting y and z in a diagram.

Does a concept exist like this?

What I already thought of:

I know that a principal component analysis can be used for this, but a PCA can only be performed after I got enough points.

I tried splitting a vector in two halves and calculated a norm for each half but it seems that I get some strange curves and jumps and this maybe breaks the definition of a norm.

Comment: This is a potentially interesting question but too vague to get a useful answer. Can you specify what properties your norm should have? What do want to get from your "visualization"? Can you be more specific if, say, $n=3$? Please edit the question to provide more information.

Comment: I tried adding more. Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused. Can you write an _explicit_  $f : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ that almost works for you, and explain why it's not quite good enough?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I was wrong that using two norms for each half of the vector does not give proper results. The solution is rather trivial.
For some "proof" I wrote a script to do a random walk in high dimensional space and used the 1-norm for each half of the vector.
The jumps I saw in my original application must have had another cause.

[image: random walk in high dimensional space]